# Midnite commander ELF viewer - what do the symbols mean?

Tags: linux, assembly, elf

I have a small program which when viewed in Midnite Commander looks like this:

```
/home/adrian/Imperas/mb_boot /startup.MICROBLAZE.elf                                                                                  486/486               100%
/home/adrian/Imperas/mb_boot/startup.MICROBLAZE.elf: ELF 32-bit MSB  executable, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
100000f0 T _actualstart
100012b4 A __bss_start
10001228 d _DYNAMIC
100012b4 A _edata
100012b4 A _end
100012a8 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
1000010c t _handle_exception
1000010c t _handle_hwexception
1000010c t _interrupt_handler
10000110 T _start
10000128 t _vector_hw_exception
10000120 t _vector_interrupt
10000118 t _vector_sw_exception
```

The various symbols eg `_vector_sw_exception` correspond to what I have in the assembly - but what do the `A`, `T`, `t` and so on mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `nm(1)` man page:

> ```
>        "A" The symbol's value is absolute, and will not be changed by
>            further linking.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>        "T"
>        "t" The symbol is in the text (code) section.
> ```

And so on.